# Broken drawing pencil

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

But in the implementation, I ran into a thing that was not clear to me.

Working pencil implementation code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QIcon, QPixmap, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QMainWindow,QWidget)


class AbstractScribbleArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self.modified = False
        self._begin = QPoint()
        self._end = QPoint()
        self._lastPoint = QPoint()
        self._pixmap = QPixmap()
        self._shape = ""

        self.myPenWidth = 10
        self.myPenColor = QColor("black")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self._begin = event.pos()
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # draw on image
        painter = QPainter(self._pixmap)
        if self._shape == 'pencil':
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth,
                                Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        self.draw(painter, self._begin, self._end, True)
        self._begin = QPoint()
        self._end = QPoint()
        self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self._pixmap, self.rect())
        if self._shape == 'pencil':
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.myPenColor, self.myPenWidth,
                                Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        self.draw(painter, self._begin, self._end, False)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.width() if self.width() > self._pixmap.width() else self._pixmap.width()
        h = self.height() if self.height() > self._pixmap.height() else self._pixmap.height()

        s = QSize(w, h)
        if s != self._pixmap.size():
            pixmap = QPixmap(self._pixmap)
            self._pixmap = QPixmap(s)
            painter = QPainter(self._pixmap)
            painter.fillRect(QRect(0, 0, w, h), Qt.white)
            painter.drawPixmap(pixmap.rect(), pixmap)
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def draw(self, painter, _begin, _end, is_released):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(640, 480)

    def set_shape(self, shape):
        self._shape = shape

    def shape(self):
        return self._shape



class ScribbleArea(AbstractScribbleArea):
    def draw(self, painter, _begin, _end, is_released):
        if _begin.isNull() or _end.isNull():
            return
        elif self.shape() == "pencil":
            self.drawPencil(painter, _begin, _end)

    def drawPencil(self, painter, _begin, _end):
        self.modified = True
        painter.drawPoint(_begin.x(), _end.y())

    def pencilOn(self):
        self.set_shape("pencil")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scribbleArea = ScribbleArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scribbleArea)

        self.pen = QAction(QIcon('Image/pen.png'), 'Карандаш', self)
        self.pen.triggered.connect(self.scribbleArea.pencilOn)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Инструменты')
        toolbar.addAction(self.pen)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that at the moment a point is drawn that can be moved along the axis. But this is not what I'm waiting for. I assume that instead of _begin.x (), _end.y () need use event.x (), event.y ().

But this does not work out because in the draw function I can not pass the argument to "event".

When I try to do something similar, the function requests event with =

```
def draw(self, painter, _begin, _end, is_released):
    if _begin.isNull() or _end.isNull():
        return
    elif self.shape() == "pencil":
        self.drawPencil(painter, event= #????)

def drawPencil(self, painter, _begin, _end):
    self.modified = True
    painter.drawPoint(event.x(), event.y())
```

I do not really understand what needs to be passed to the event so that the function works.

There is one more implementation of the pencil function:

```
def draw_pencil(self, event):
    painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
    self.modified = True
    self._lastPoint = event.pos()
    self.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it has not understood the solution of the logic of the painting of the shapes, in the case of a shape while dragging the mouse the previous shape has to be erased, and when the mouse is released it must be painted in permanent memory , in this case the `QPixmap`. But in the case of a pencil it is different because while it is dragging it must be painted in permanent memory, so the class that implements does not work for it, so we must implement it in the new class, remember that in programming you have to be ordered, each class must have a specific task.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class AbstractShapeScribbleArea(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AbstractShapeScribbleArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self._start = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap() 
        self._shape = ""

        self._color = QtGui.QColor("black")
        self._pen_width = 1

        self._pen = QtGui.QPen(self._color, self._pen_width, 
            QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._start = event.pos()
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractShapeScribbleArea, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractShapeScribbleArea, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        self.draw_shape(painter, self._start, self._end, True)

        self._start = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.update()
        super(AbstractShapeScribbleArea, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self._pixmap, self.rect())
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        self.draw_shape(painter, self._start, self._end, False)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.width() if self.width() > self._pixmap.width() else self._pixmap.width()
        h = self.height() if self.height() > self._pixmap.height() else self._pixmap.height()

        s = QtCore.QSize(w, h)
        if s != self._pixmap.size():
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self._pixmap)
            self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(s)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
            painter.fillRect(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, w, h), QtCore.Qt.white)
            painter.drawPixmap(pixmap.rect(), pixmap)
        super(AbstractShapeScribbleArea, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def draw_shape(self, painter, start, end, is_released):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)

    def set_pen_width(self, width):
        self._pen.setWidth(width)

    def set_pen_color(self, color):
        self._pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor(color))

    def set_shape(self, shape):
        self._shape =shape

    def shape(self):
        return self._shape


class ScribbleArea(AbstractShapeScribbleArea):
    def draw_shape(self, painter, start, end, is_released):
        if start.isNull() or end.isNull():
            return
        if self.shape() == "rectangle":
            self.draw_rectangle(painter, start, end)
        elif self.shape() == "ellipse":
            self.draw_ellipse(painter, start, end)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.shape() == "pencil" and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            setattr(self, "pencil_start", event.pos())
            self.draw_pencil(event.pos(), event.pos())
        else:
            super(ScribbleArea, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.shape() == "pencil" and event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            pencil_start = getattr(self, "pencil_start")
            self.draw_pencil(pencil_start, event.pos())
            setattr(self, "pencil_start", event.pos())
        else:
            super(ScribbleArea, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.shape() == "pencil":
            delattr(self, "pencil_start")
        else:
            super(ScribbleArea, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def draw_rectangle(self, painter, start, end):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(start, end)
        painter.drawRect(rect)

    def draw_ellipse(self, painter, start, end):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(start, end)
        painter.drawEllipse(rect)

    def draw_pencil(self, start, end):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        painter.drawLine(start, end)
        self.update()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def rectangleOn(self):
        self.set_shape("rectangle")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def ellipseOn(self):
        self.set_shape("ellipse")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def pencilOn(self):
        self.set_shape("pencil")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scribbleArea = ScribbleArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(scribbleArea)

        rectangle = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Image/rectangle.png'), 'Rectangle', self)
        rectangle.triggered.connect(scribbleArea.rectangleOn)
        ellipse = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Image/Ellipse.png'), 'Ellipse', self)
        ellipse.triggered.connect(scribbleArea.ellipseOn)
        pen = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Image/pen.png'), 'Pencil', self)
        pen.triggered.connect(scribbleArea.pencilOn)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        toolbar.addAction(rectangle)
        toolbar.addAction(ellipse)
        toolbar.addAction(pen)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I can not express my gratitude to you in words c:
Already so many times you helped me с: